# regex to highlight text between tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a text which contains text in between `<abbr></abbr>` tags

I want to highlight the `<abbr></abbr>` tags which contains no other `<abbr></abbr>` tags in between the tags. Here is the sample

```
 content example <abbr variable-title="notepad 1">data <abbr variable-title="notepad 2">sample value </abbr>sample conten</abbr>
```

In this I want to highlight only `<abbr variable-title="notepad 2">sample value </abbr>` as it has no nested `<abbr></abbr>`

How to I write regex to get such single `<abbr></abbr>` tags highlighted

Comment: This isn't something you want JS/Regex for. This is more for [CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaScript use:

```
str.replace(/(<abbr )([^>]*>[^<]*(<(?!abbr)[^<]*)*?<\/abbr>)/gi, "$1class=\"highlight\" $2");
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ5hQ6/2).

Then define a class `abbr.highlight` in your CSS.

Comment: please help me in this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782183/regex-which-identified-words-with-tags

Answer (score 1):

Might try this `/<abbr>(\S.*?)<\/abbr>/gi`

Comment: Not getting highlighted. Please check here https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/41

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!